# Dealing with the probability of a state occurring in Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

In Markov Chain, when we are dealing with a situation such as:

$X_n$ eventually reaches $C$, where $C$ is a subset of the total possible states.

where $X_n$ is the state at the $n^{th}$ step. A book mentions that if the initial state $i \in C$, it is certain that eventually at some point of time,  $X_n$ will eventually reach $C$.

I am not able to understand why this is so.

Comment: I assume that $X_0 \in C$ doesn't count as $X_n$ eventually reaching $C$ (because in this case the question is trivial). If my assumption is correct, then additional hypotheses are required, because it is possible that $C$ is not just transient but "instantly transient" i.e. $P(X_{n+1} \in C \mid X_n=x)=0$ for all $x \in C$.

Comment: My guess is that the book is making the trivial observation that we know we get there at some point if we are already there (“at some point” includes the initial time). In fact, it is standard for such problems to turn all states in C into trapping states where, once we get there, we never leave.

Comment: Can I post the screenshot of the book, or it might be some copyright issue? @Michael I think that's the argument in the book, but as Ian mentioned, it is not certain whether $X_n$ includes $X_0$

Comment: It'd be better to retype the relevant passage (a few sentences should suffice).  Please also state the title, author, etc, of the book.

Comment: Usually you define $p_i$ as the probability of eventually reaching $C$, given we start in state $i$, and then write recursive equations for $p_i$ assuming the boundary conditions $p_i=1$ for all $i\in C$. I would be surprised if any book did it differently.

Comment: Book Source: [link](https://www.math.vt.edu/people/day/IntroChains/IntroChains.pdf)  Page 11

Comment: It is as expected. The book indeed allows the hitting time to be some time $n \geq 0$, which indeed includes the initial time $0$. It even uses the same language of being “trivial” that the hitting probability is 1 given the initial state is in $C$.

Comment: How to mark it solved?

Comment: @user3656142 Answer your own question on this post and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book indeed allows the hitting time to be some time n≥0, which indeed includes the initial time 0. It even uses the same language of being “trivial” that the hitting probability is 1 given the initial state is in C.

Answer by @Michael in the comments.